# How to make suspend functions finish in the order they were started?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

For two suspend functions foo and bar, I would like to make it so that if foo is started  before bar then foo will always finish before bar. Foo and bar can be passed in by different callers and foo and bar can have no knowledge of one another.

I am trying to create a class which maintains some state in order to do so, but am having trouble getting it to work. The class exposes a function that callers can use to serialize suspend functions that looks like this:

```
suspend fun <T> runSerialized(asyncFn: suspend () -> T): T = supervisorScope {
    val mutationDeferred = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { asyncFn() }
    var currAsyncFn: Deferred<*>? = null
    try {
      for (curr in enqueue(mutationDeferred)) {
        currAsyncFn = curr
        curr.await()
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      if (currAsyncFn == asyncFn) {
        throw e
      }
    } finally {
      withContext(NonCancellable) { mutex.withLock { mutationList.remove(mutationDeferred) } }
    }
    mutationDeferred.await()
  }

private suspend fun enqueue(asyncFn: Deferred<*>) =
  mutex.withLock {
    mutationList.add(asyncFn)
    asyncFn.start()
    return@withLock mutationList.toList()
  }
```

However, this doesn't work because there's a period between when the mutationDeferred finishes and we're cleaning up the class state in the finally block where racing can happen with other passed in suspend funs.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to ensure foo to return before bar, or do you want to ensure `runSerialized(foo)` returns before `runSerialized(bar)` ? Becaise it is two different things. The former is impossible, but the later might be possible (I do not have th solution currently, I have to think more about it)

Comment: I want to ensure runSerialized(foo) returns before runSerialized(bar). This can give me the desired behavior of foo always returning before bar by sending both foo and bar through runSerialized.